# fade in from left to right one by one

Tags: jquery, html

I have the code to make the image fade in together from left to right , but i want them to fade in one by one from left to right  . How would i do that?

The code demo is in  http://jsfiddle.net/02dmq1n4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fade-right").animate({left:100, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 14%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2, #div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.fade-right {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; 
  position: absolute; 
  display: none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fade-right">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in fiddle you give code with ".fade-right1"  ? where is this element ?

Comment: oh i take it out, it was just some experimenting to make it fade in one by one. Forgot to take that out of the script. sorry

Comment: ok so you want to fade div block inside fade-right?

Comment: yeah pretty much, as long as they fade in one by one any implementation should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code   . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/02dmq1n4/4/)

CSS

```
#div1{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 5%;
   margin-left: 14%;
   background-color: blue;
   display:none;
 }

 #div2,#div3{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 5%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   background-color: blue;
   display:none;
 }

 .fade-right{
    width: 100%;
   float:left; 
   position:absolute; 
 }
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var delay = 0;
   $('.fade-right div').each(function(){ 
      $(this).delay(delay).animate({
         left:100, opacity:"show"
     },1500);
     delay += 1000;
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".fade-right div").each(function(index) {
      $(this).delay(800*index).fadeIn(4000).css({'left':'100'});
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/02dmq1n4/7/)**